# how to dynamically get the list of messaging apps on the phone

Tags: android

I know how to get the list of installed applications on the mobile phone.

Is it possible to *dynamically* get the list of installed **messaging apps** on the phone like *whatsapp*, *viber* etc?

How to achieve this through code?

**EDIT:** I am specifically looking for apps which are capable of sending messages through mobile data or wifi.. amongst which some examples include whatsapp or viber.

Comment: No..its not possible.we cant determine app belongs to specific type.for this you need to maintain some list of Messaging applications in database or some where and check with all your installed applications..

Comment: Hmmm.. that is what I am doing now.  But when I checked on a Samsung S3 phone.. such a feature was available. So I was wondering how..

Comment: Look into the permission list used by all those applications. You can identify all those by common permission

Comment: Excellent suggestion. Though I have to wait for few days to try it :-)

Comment: You will first need to decide what a "messaging app" means to you, in some concrete terms. Saying "like whatsapp, viber" is not very specific.

Comment: My criteria is any app which is capable of sending messages though mobile data or wifi..such as whatsapp , viber and so on.

Comment: @CommonsWare: I have edited my question accordingly.

Comment: That is not an improvement. What is a "message"? Is Yahoo Mail a "messaging" app? How about Skype? Twitter? Snapchat? Web browsers?

Comment: @CommonsWare: Never mind. I got an idea from the comments here. Thanks for taking the time to look into this question. :)